# Converting binary to decimal in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have written piece of code that converts binary to decimal in XSLT 2.0 and got stuck with adding up of the values each math power value for the result. Please help.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" extension-element-prefixes="xs">

  <xsl:template match="SUBSCRIBER">

    <xsl:variable name="binary" select="'0101'"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="for $i in 1 to string-length($binary) return $i">

      <xsl:variable name="powerVal">
        <xsl:call-template name="mathpower">
          <xsl:with-param name="base" select="2"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="power" select="(string-length($binary)-.)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="number(substring($binary,.,1))*number($powerVal)"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="'--'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="mathpower">
    <xsl:param name="base" select="0"/>
    <xsl:param name="power" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="result" select="1"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$power = 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="mathpower">
          <xsl:with-param name="base" select="$base"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="power" select="$power - 1"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="result" select="$result * $base"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need an expensive power function for this task.  Here is a template that's also XSLT 1.0 compatible that recursively "eats up" the binary string, multiplying by two and adding the next binary digit.

I used a template here because templates can have default parameters, in this case the parameter `integer` that should not be provided when calling the template from "outside".

```
<xsl:template name="bin2int">
  <xsl:param name="binaryString"/>
  <xsl:param name="integer" select="0"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$binaryString=''">
      <xsl:value-of select="$integer"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="bin2int">
        <xsl:with-param name="binaryString" select="substring($binaryString,2)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="integer" select="2*$integer + number(substring($binaryString,1,1))"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XSLT 2.0 then consider to use functions and not templates as they are then callable in expressions. And `power` has been done for sure, a search finds http://users.atw.hu/xsltcookbook2/xsltckbk2-chp-3-sect-5.html with

```
<!-- Power -->
<xsl:function name="ckbk:power" as="xs:double">
   <xsl:param name="base" as="xs:double"/>
   <xsl:param name="exp" as="xs:integer"/>
   <xsl:sequence 
        select="if ($exp lt 0) then ckbk:power(1.0 div $base, -$exp) 
                else 
                if ($exp eq 0) 
                then 1e0 
                else $base * ckbk:power($base, $exp - 1)"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: Many Thanks. But How can i sum up all the decimal values. For example 0101 should lead to decimal 5

Comment: @Hari something like `sum(for $i in 1 to string-length($binary) return ckbk:power(2, string-length($binary)-$i) * substring($binary, $i, 1))` should work.